# Sitecore 9.0.2 and Azure PaaS based live website gives '502' error few times in a day

Tags: paas, caching, session-state, iis, performance

We have our public website in Sitecore 9.0.2 and it is in Azure PaaS infrastructure, from last few days the website gives '502 following error message' at specific times in a day(8 (am or pm), 9(am or pm), and 10(am or pm)) and website becomes unavailable to the users.

**502 Error Message**

```
 Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

Checked the application logs and everything but can't find anything specific about what is going on, top errors reported in application insights are '400','404', and '500'.
I have tried this as well in the web config file but no joy. RequestQueueLimitPerSession to 50 from 25 (Web.config)
Can anybody help on this or has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Have you seen any CPU spikes at that time? Some timeouts?

Comment: Yes,it shows CPU spike and web app slow at these time but could not found why this happens,also web app is not completely crashed, but slow and only for 1 to 4 minutes window at three specific times,so some users get '502' but for some it is ok as well.

Comment: 502 on azure may be caused by timeouts

Comment: But very strange thing is,this happens at three specific times 8:05 am,9:05 am and 10 am for 2-5 minutes window and it is intermittent as well,some times on browser refresh site again loads ok,also other than mentioned times website is ok and works fine for rest of the day.

Comment: Check if there was any job executed at that time, like content testing index rebuild or screenshots generation. Or republish of part of content tree